# xdotool does not work for terminal window copy paste

Tags: x11, xdotool

I'm using Ubuntu 22 and i have set up two custom shortcuts via settings (works for all windows i have tested so far).

```
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+c (-> super+c)
xdotool getactivewindow key ctrl+v (-> super+v)
```

Then changed the terminal shortcuts of copy to `Ctrl+C` and paste to `Ctrl+V`.

Now, when i press `super+v` with an active terminal open nothing happens. However, i would expect that it pastes my text into the terminal. When pressing `ctrl+v` it works. How can i make this work?

Furthermore i have changed the terminal interruption signal to `Strg+I` with `stty intr ^I`.
I also disabled the `super` key default behaviour when pressed to nothing with `gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key '' t`.